# Ansible: how to start consul-cluster

Tags: ansible, consul, ansible-2.x

I have a ansible-playbook to configure consul with (3 servers (1 bootstrap)) and 3 clients.
First, I want to execute the bootstrap this is the console command:

```
vagrant@172.16.8.191$ consul agent -config-dir /etc/consul.d/bootstrap
```

Then while bootstrap is executing, I want to start consul in the others servers of the cluster. I have the next in ansible:

```
-  name: start consul
   service: name=consul state=restarted enabled=yes
```

My problem is, how can I stop the next execution using Ansible:

```
consul agent -config-dir /etc/consul.d/bootstrap
```

If it is other way to start consul-cluster by Ansible I'm thrilled to know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution answer:

I have change my consul config on clients and servers to auto-create the cluster, so when you start the nodes computers, the cluster start and consul start automatically.
To do this, I use the next configuration:

Client:

```
{
   "bind_addr":"172.16.8.194",
    "client_addr":"0.0.0.0",
    "server": false,
    "datacenter": "ikerlan-Consul",
    "data_dir": "/var/consul",
    "ui_dir": "/home/ikerlan/dist",
    "log_level": "WARN",
    "encrypt": "XXXXXX",
    "enable_syslog": true,
    "retry_join": [172.16.8.191,172.16.8.192,172.16.8.193]
}
```

Server:

```
{
    "bind_addr":"0.0.0.0",
    "client_addr":"0.0.0.0",
    "bootstrap": false,
    "server": true,
    "datacenter": "ikerlan-Consul",
    "data_dir": "/var/consul",
    "ui_dir": "/home/ikerlan/dist",
    "log_level": "WARN",
    "encrypt": "XXXXXX",
    "enable_syslog": true,
    "retry_join": [172.16.8.191,172.16.8.192,172.16.8.193],
   "bootstrap_expect": 3
}
```